# How to put scroll on a div with a fixed width having a table inside it which add dynamically td with a fixed width in HTML

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have an issue with HTML .

I have a table inside a div. The width of the div is `200px` and `td` will add dynamically. So I had the following code which can produce a similar output. Each `td` will have `100px` width. So when I add 5 `td` with `100px` it will be around 500px. But the scroll bar is not appearing and the width of the column is automatically re-sizing.

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;width:200px;overflow:auto">
    <table style="border:1px solid black;">
        <tr style="border:1px solid black;">
            <td style="border:1px solid black;width:100px">1</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;width:100px">2</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;width:100px">3</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;width:100px">4</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;width:100px">5</td>
         </tr>
    </table>
 <div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L93UG/

But I need to have a scroll for the div when the new `td` is added.But it will actually auto adjust the size and no scroll is appearing.I cannot add the width to table. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the div and `overflow:scroll` or `overflow-x:scroll` and remove the fixed width from the TDs:

http://jsfiddle.net/L93UG/1/

Comment: Just wrap the content within the TDs with a div or something: http://jsfiddle.net/L93UG/3/